# How can I become Steve again?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have changed my Minecraft skin and now I feel a bit nostalgic. I have tried to find a solution to this already but all I can find is possible "Steve skins" on the various skin websites. I want the original skin exactly as it would be if I created a new account.

I also can't seem to find anything on the Mojang account preferences to reset this back to its original state.

How can I change back to the original Steve skin?

Comment: Do the Steve skins not look exactly the same as the original?

Comment: I believe there used to be (don't know if there still is) an option to revert your skin to Steve I'm Minecraft.net

Comment: I know it wouldn't look right in the question title, but the name is actually spelt "Steve?", question mark included.

Comment: @Zibbobz i can't find any reference to that anywhere, even on the mojang website when they mension steve it is just "Steve"

Comment: I think a more useful title for those finding this question with a search would be something more like "How do I remove my Minecraft skin?"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Simple Fix

Navigate to [the minecraft profile page](http://minecraft.net/profile) and click the "reset" button under "reset your skin".

(*As pointed out by @Quinte in* [*his answer*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/193129/74333))

#### Workaround

You can get the Steve Skin on Minecraft.net

1. Log in, go to Profile
2. [Download the reference skin](https://minecraft.net/images/char.png)
3. Upload the reference skin

In this case you will have a Steve skin.

#### Problems

Uploading the reference skin still counts as there being a skin, because, well, it is there. The problem here is that skins uploaded to the skin server take precedence over skins included in Resource Packs (e.g. the default skin in Sphax PureBDCraft).

<s>Unfortunately there's no way to remove the skin from the skin-server completely.</s>

[image: STEVE]

Comment: Unfortunately that is what i want is for it to be completely back to "factory settings" as it were

Comment: rolling back, as even if the new edits add to the answer, or remove incorrect content, it is still deviating from author intent. If you have more information, leave it as a comment, or better yet, propose a better-put-together answer.

Comment: I am personally unsure as to how to proceed with this answer. It is utterly outdated and is now useless to anyone, seeing that it provides a workaround for a problem that has an actual fix. Editing this answer to reflect this is seems a little wrong as it will change the content of the answer entirely.

Comment: For now, I have edited the answer by Quinte to have better wording, seeing that it was the first answer to mention the reset button. @Flaunting should probably accept that answer instead of mine.

Comment: @Aequitas, I agree with you in why the information should be put up, entirely. However, deliberately adding in and removing content goes against the original authors intent. In the posts you linked, they all fall back to the response from the one user (a mod). That user, as well as a few other mods, also specify that old information should be "crossed out" with a warning that the information is out of date, instead of removed. There is also general consensus that one should simply put a comment up, to alert the original user to update their answer.

Comment: I had assumed the best way to present a more up to date answer was to post your own answer, including all the "still applicable" information, as well as all new information. I might ask about this more specifically on meta, as I personally believe your method to be more effective, but would like clarification in terms of adding new content, over updating old content.

Comment: @Aequitas, [here is the meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/updating-an-out-of-date-answer-versus-keeping-author-intent). You should go on and have your say. I have seen this argument before, for rejecting and backrolling edits. If this is indeed allowed on here, this meta can become our direct reference that these sort of content additions are permitted.

Comment: @Aequitas the point here is that changing the answer to reflect the current situation is not an update to the answer. It's a **complete rewrite of the answer**. Leaving the old answer labeled as a workaround is entirely pointless, there is not a single person that will ever need that workaround, now that the reset button is there. It's just useless information now and should not be there any more. Changing my answer in this way will turn it into Quinte's answer, which is why ideally, it should be accepted instead.

Answer (score 9):

Theres a "Reset" button on your [profile page on Minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net/profile), under "Reset your skin". Clicking it will restore your skin to Steve/Alex.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution!

- Go to https://minecraft.net/
- Go to **Profile**
- Click on **Reset** under reset your skin.

You are covered in Steve's skin! I hope you're happy.

Comment: [You're 9 months late.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/193129/4163) but +1 for following formatting conventions.

Answer (score -1):

As of August 2015, you can still go to http://www.minecraft.net/profile and select "Reset Skin" near the bottom of the page, this will remove your skin from the skin server and it will appear as if you have not selected a skin. Giving you the default skin of your resource pack.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in answers prior to this one and does not add to those answers. As per the [Help Center on what answers are deleted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) and the [meta] post, [How do we handle duplicate answers?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4971/4797) - this answer could be deleted.